# Is there a newer version than Xcode 3.1.2?

Tags: iphone, xcode

For some reason the Interface Builder of Xcode 3.1.2 has graphical bugs. It draws its interface badly and messes up everything. It's a graphics problem on a brand new MacBook Pro. Two months ago that was not the case. But Xcode doesn't offer me an update-function, does it?

Answer (score 1):

you are on the latest version and i noticed that too no auto update either.

i would just try re-downloading and reinstalling

Comment: good idea! I hope this doesn't force me to get the new iPhone OS on my iPod touch in order to test my app...I'll see...

Comment: sweet...u should be able to compile down to older OS versions though..let me know :)

Answer (score 0):

XCode 3.1.3 is the latest.  I get this through the Apple Developer Connection.  If you re-download the latest SDK you should get it, although it might only be available with the OS3.1 beta.

3.1.2 Draws fine for me.  Could there be some other application running which mucks around with your MBP's rendering?  Try stopping all other applications in your task bar

Comment: Thanks a lot. I quit all other apps and also tried switching between low and high performance graphics card through the energy saving options. Now I gotta see what's happening after re-installing everything.

Comment: Thanks guys, I think the problem is gone now. I've re-installed.